# How to iterate over multiple slices of a list

Tags: python

```
for fi in files[0:10.605:615]:
    print ic1.location + fi
    ccd = CCDData.read(ic1.location + fi, unit = u.adu)
    bias_lst.append(ccd)
```

How can I add [605:615] to[0:10]?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by 'add to'? Also, the code you provided is not valid Python code because you used 10.605, a float, as an argument to a slice operation, which is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
from itertools import chain

for fi in chain(files[0:10], files[605:615]):
    print fi
```

`itertools.chain` will make an iterator that will return all elements from the first iterable, then from the second, third, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the useful info too! It's the first time I use this page!